# Duplicate string resource in Android Studio Gradle build

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, duplicates

I am building and Android application using Android Studio using the Gradle build framework. It depends on one custom library. While building it is showing error in resource merging task. It show as Duplicate Resource for few string resource ID's which are defined in both library and the application.

The same works fin in eclipse.

Help me with possible solution.

Comment: check dependency of your project. maybe you try to include projects which have duplicate resources.

Comment: Try clarifying where those IDs are defined and how the library is included, and posting extracts of the resouce files containing those ids and gradle definitions . Resource override works in Android Studio the same way it does in Eclipse, so you must be doing something differently.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a duplicate string resource in one project http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

On eclipse all work because eclipse doesn't merge everything element of project (for example manifest).

So, you must rename your string and change your code where u use it to fix